# How to import FBSession.h in Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use FBSession in my Swift project. But I have no idea how to import it.

I have imported these in my Bridging Header

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

Any ideas please?

I am trying to convert the code below to Swift, but I can't seem to use FBSession

```
// Whenever a person opens app, check for a cached session
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {

  // If there's one, just open the session silently, without showing the user the login UI
  [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
                                     allowLoginUI:NO
                                completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                  // Handler for session state changes
                                  // Call this method EACH time the session state changes,
                                  //  NOT just when the session open
                                  [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                }];
```

Answer (score 1):

`FBSession` is the name the class had in the 3.x branch of the SDK, the headers you import are from a 4.x version though where that class does not exist anymore.

Facebook has an [Upgrade Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x#3to4) for this in their documentation which will guide you through the process of migrating from 3.x to 4.x